# Powershell remove nth character in place in filename

Tags: powershell, file, rename

I would like to remove the 12th character in a list of files using powershell.

```
BH_072720_A001.pdf<br>
BH_072720_A002.pdf<br>
BH_072720_A003.pdf<br>
BH_072720_A004.pdf<br>
```

to

```
BH_072720_A01.pdf<br>
BH_072720_A02.pdf<br>
BH_072720_A03.pdf<br>
BH_072720_A04.pdf<br>
```

I was trying to alter this to work but I'm not getting it.. I know this is simple but I'm trying to learn.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\ITLT20\OneDrive\Desktop\02 - Herald Pages' -Filter *.pdf -Recurse | foreach { $_ | rename-item -newname ($_.Name -replace '(.{11})..(.+)','$1$2')  }
```

Comment: Use `^(.{11}).(.+)$','$1$2'`. Since you do care about parsing the entire string, you should use `^` beginning of string and `$` end of string anchors. `..` is two characters rather than one (`.`).

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\ITLT20\OneDrive\Desktop\02 - Herald Pages' -Filter *.pdf -Recurse) |
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '^(.{11}).(.+)$','$1$2' }
```

One problematic issue is using `..` rather than just `.`. Each `.` in a regex string matches any character. So `..` matches two characters. You are effectively removing character 12 and 13. Replacing `Name` could have an issue if the extension contains character 12. It may be wiser to use `BaseName` instead.

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\ITLT20\OneDrive\Desktop\02 - Herald Pages' -Filter *.pdf -Recurse) |
        Rename-Item -NewName { "{0}{1}" -f ($_.BaseName -replace '(?<=^.{11}).'),$_.Extension }
```

Personally, I would use anchors for the beginning (`^`) and the end (`$`) of the string if I want to parse the entire string. Your intention is clear then.

[Rename-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7) supports [delay-bind scripting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7#:%7E:text=In%20the%20PowerShell%20programming%20language%2C%20a%20script%20block%20is%20a,accept%20arguments%20and%20return%20values.&text=Like%20functions%2C%20script%20blocks%20can,%2C%20Process%20%2C%20and%20End%20keywords.) for the `-NewName` parameter when piping in a `FileInfo` object. This can remove the need for `foreach-object` when piping from `Get-ChildItem`.

---

As an aside, `$_.Name.Remove(11,1)` is more concise. However, it will throw an error if there aren't at least 12 characters in your file name. `-replace` does not have that issue.

Comment: Thank you!  The only issue is that it affects the first filename different than the rest.  It seems to be removing 2 characters from the first filename, and 1 (correctly) from the rest of the filenames.  So I'm getting:  BH_072720_A1.pdf, BH_072720_A02.pdf, BH_072720_A03.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Or as a character array.  Added the parentheses so the dir completes first.

```
(dir) | rename-item -newname { -join $_.name[0..10 + 12..17] } -whatif

What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: 
C:\Users\js\foo\BH_072720_A001.pdf Destination: C:\Users\js\foo\BH_072720_A01.pdf".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: 
C:\Users\js\foo\BH_072720_A002.pdf Destination: C:\Users\js\foo\BH_072720_A02.pdf".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: 
C:\Users\js\foo\BH_072720_A003.pdf Destination: C:\Users\js\foo\BH_072720_A03.pdf".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: 
C:\Users\js\foo\BH_072720_A004.pdf Destination: C:\Users\js\foo\BH_072720_A04.pdf".
```

Comment: Thanks @js2010!  Strangely it also is removing 2 characters from the first file rather than only 1.  The rest of the files are being renamed correctly.  Even the whatif shows the first file correctly but when actually run, it removes 2 characters?  Any ideas why its doing that?

Comment: Sorry, that's a common problem.  Put parentheses around the first part so it finishes first.  Otherwise you're modifying the very thing you're looping on.

Comment: Got it.  Perfect!
Thanks guys !